# Allow Fill-in Choices in survey list

Tags: sharepoint

I have Creted a survey in sharepoint 2007.To add a comment box at the end of each question,i have selected ALLOW FILL-IN-CHOICES to be yes..So when i check my servey on site,it comes with a default tet"SPecify your own value" Is there any way i can change it and put my own custom text.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

when you say  "...change it and put my own custom text." I assume you don't want the field to say "Specify your own value" as the description?

In my experience, you can't do it OOTB, you need to edit the edit.aspx form for the list in SharePoint Designer. If you've never done that, I would recommend you read up on how do alter the 3 forms of a list.